# Clipping a layer file in ArcGIS 10.5 to a polygon but can't retain landcover classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, arcgis-10.5

I'm trying to clip a layer file using ArcGIS 10.5 of landcover classes to a specific polygon however each time I do this I can't retain the categories of landcover classes in the clipped portion.

Steps: 
click toolbox

click on analysis tools

click on extract

select clip

input: landcover class layer

clip feature: county shapefile

name the output feature class

click OK button

Comment: Please [edit] your question to outline the process you are following to perform your clip

Comment: Are you just missing the class names or are the actual rasters values changing? Dropping attributes is the common behavior when manipulating rasters. You can simply join the table of the original data to the new rasters table.

Comment: The clip only retains the lines of the original layer file but has no landcover data associated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some work I answered my own question.  I needed to click on properties of the clipped layer and change the symbology to match a category from the attribute table...

Comment: You can accept your own answer so that people looking at this question realize it has been answered. Thank you for following up and posting what you found!